# only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array called predictions

```
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  dtype=int64)
```

I try to convert this array to dataframe column but have an error mentioned in the title. I try to convert elements of ndarray to an integer, but none of this works.

```
Xtest["Survived"] = [int(x) for x in predictions]
Xtest["Survived"] = [x.astype(int) for x in predictions]
Xtest["Survived"] = pd.Series(predictions)
```

Also when I type

```
type(predictions[1])
```

I got

```
numpy.int64
```

Comment: what is `print(predictions.shape)` and `print(Xtest.shape)` ?

Comment: (418,) (418, 4)

Comment: Is `Xtest['Survived']` right?

Comment: what do you mean? It's non-existent column which I try to create using ndarray

Comment: To me it looks like `Xtest` is an ndarray, and not a DataFrame. Check that.

Comment: right! Checked and changed. Everything works now, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As solved in the comments, the error is thrown because `Xdata` was an ndarray and not a DataFrame. An ndarray can't be indexed with a string ("Survived"), thus the error message about indeces. The problem is unrelated to the predictions data. If `Xtest` is a DataFrame, any of the lines above should work. They could be simplified to

```
Xtest["Survived"] = predictions
```